# If $Σ$ is endowed with the initial topology $\cal T_ Φ$ corresponding to the collection $Φ$ then $σ_i⟶σ$ iff $φ(σ_i)⟶φ(σ)$ for any $φ∈Φ$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, nets

When I started to study topology of compact convergence it seemed to me that there was something not said explicitly that really help to understand better this topology so that I observed that for any metri space $(Y,d)$ and for any topological space $(X,\cal T)$ if $Y^X$ is equipped with the compact topology $\mathcal T_C$ corresponding to $d$ then any projection $\pi_K$ of $Y^X$ onto $Y^K$ with $K\in\mathcal P(X)$ compact is continuous when $Y^K$ is equipped with topology of uniform convergence $\mathcal T_\infty(Y^K)$ and really this is true since actually $\mathcal T_C$ is the initial topology corresponding to these projections as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4612060/736008) is proved. Anyway, when Munkres into his Topology text started to explain the topology of compact convergence then he gives as exercise to show that a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\omega}$ in $Y^X$ converges to any function $f$ if and only if for any compact $K\in\mathcal P(X)$ the restricted sequence $\big(f_n|_K\big)_{n\in\omega}$ converges to $f|_K$ so that I observed that this was trivial if the following proposition

> **Proposition 1**
>
> If $\Sigma$ is a set equipped with the initial topology $\cal T_\Phi$ corresponding to the collection of functions $\Phi$ then a net $(\sigma_i)_{i\in I}$ in $\Sigma$ based on the directed set $(I,\preceq_I)$ converges to an $\sigma\in\Sigma$ if and only if for any $\varphi\in\Phi$ the net $\big(\varphi(\sigma_i)\big)_{i\in I}$ converges to $\varphi(\sigma)$

holds.

So, I observed that if $(\sigma_i)_{i\in I}$ converges to any $\sigma$ then by continuity of $\varphi\in\Phi$ the net $\big(\varphi(\sigma_i)\big)_{i\in I}$ converges to $\varphi(\sigma)$. However, for any $\varphi\in\Phi$ let be $\Lambda_\varphi$ the codomain of $\varphi$ and so $\cal T_\varphi$ the corresponding topology for $\Lambda_\varphi$ so that if $A_\sigma\in\cal T_\Phi$ is a(n) (open) neighborhood of $\sigma$ then there exists $(\boldsymbol\varphi,\boldsymbol A)\in\prod_{p\in q}\Phi\times\prod_{p\in q}\cal T_{\varphi_p}$ with $q\in\omega$ such that
$$
\sigma\in\bigcap_{p\in q}\varphi^{-1}_p[A_p]\subseteq A_\sigma
$$
where we put
$$
\varphi_p:=\boldsymbol\varphi(p)\quad\text{and}\quad A_p:=\boldsymbol A(p)
$$
for any $p\in q$. So if $\big(\varphi(\sigma_i)\big)_{i\in I}$ converges to $\varphi(\sigma)$ for each $\varphi\in\Phi$ then for any $p\in q$ there exists $i_p\in I$ such that
$$
\varphi(\sigma_i)\in A_p
$$
for any $i\succeq_I i_p$ so that fixing **by cofinality** $i_0\in I$ such that
$$
i_p\preceq_I i_0
$$
for any $p\in q$ then for any $i\succeq_I i_0$ we have
$$
\sigma_i\in\bigcap_{p\in q}\varphi^{-1}_p[A_p]\subseteq A_\sigma
$$
which proves that $(\sigma_i)_{i\in I}$ converges to $\sigma$.

So, I realise that what I did can appear a not hard result so that the question can be reputed unnecessary but I decided to pose it because many (notable) authors (e.g. Engelking, Willard, Kelley etc...) prove proposition $1$ only when $\Sigma$ is just a product of any collection $\frak S$ and this led me to think that it could not be true if this is not. So, could someone help me, please?

Comment: What is $\omega$ in "there exists $(\boldsymbol\varphi,\boldsymbol A)\in\prod_{p\in q}\Phi\times\prod_{p\in q}\cal T_{\varphi_p}$ with $q\in\omega$"?

Comment: I do not think that your post contains a question.  In your answer you prove that the initial topology is uniquely characterized by the property in Proposition 1, but you didn't ask this. Perhaps you should edit your question in this sense.

Comment: @KritikerderElche So, ω is only the set of natural numbers: indeed, in Set Theory and even more in Topology is usual to denote the set of natural numbers with the corresponding ordinal ω. Moreover, I ask to prove or disprove the proposition 1 and since I concluded it is true then for confirmation I showed into the answer that 1 holds as more general results, that's all. So could you say anything about my wiki answer or about proposition $1$? Do you think it is not true?

Comment: It is true. And I think it is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of Proposition 1 contained in your question is correct. In [your wiki-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4616246/736008) you prove more, namely that the initial topology is the **unique topology** on $\Sigma$ with the property

> A net $(\sigma)_{i\in I}$ in $\Sigma$ based on the directed set $(I,\preceq_I)$ converges to any $\sigma$ if and only if the net $\big(\varphi(\sigma_i)\big)_{i\in I}$ converges to $\varphi(\sigma)$ for any $\varphi\in\Phi$.

Your proof is correct, but there is an alternative and more general theorem covering uniqueness.

**Theorem.** A topology on a set $X$ is uniquely determined by its convergent nets. More precisely, the closed subsets of $X$ are characterized as follows:
$A \subset X$ is closed if and only for each net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ with $x_i \in A$ and $x_i \to x \in X$ one has $x \in A$.

**Proof.** Let $A \subset X$ be closed and $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ be a net with $x_i \in A$ and $x_i \to x \in X$. Assume $x \notin A$. Then $U = X \setminus A$ is an open neigborhood of $x$ which must contain some $x_i$ because $x_i \to x$. This is a contradiction, therefore $x \in A$.

To prove the converse assume that for each net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ with $x_i \in A$ and $x_i \to x \in X$ one has $x \in A$. Now consider $x \in \overline A$ . This means that each open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a point $x_U \in A$. The set $\mathcal U(x)$ of all open neighborhoods if $x$ in $X$ can be partially ordered via $U \preceq V$ if $V \subset U$. This makes $(\mathcal U(x),\preceq )$ a directed set and $(x_U)$ a net with $x_U \in A$. Then $x_U \to x$ because for each $U \in \mathcal U(x)$ one has $x_V \in V \subset U$ for all $V \succeq U$. Therefore $x \in A$.

Comment: Perfect, all clear: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Analysing the corresponding proofs for product topology I elaborated by myself a possibile answer: what I did seemed to me reasonable to the point that I deliberated to condivide it as wiki answer, hoping someone can add some details or correct it whether it is not correct or whether it has some imperfections. Thanks in advance for read it!!!**

Actually $\cal T_\Phi$ is the unique topology on $\Sigma$ for which the statement

> A net $(\sigma)_{i\in I}$ in $\Sigma$ based on the directed set $(I,\preceq_I)$ converges to any $\sigma$ if and only if the net $\big(\varphi(\sigma_i)\big)_{i\in I}$ converges to $\varphi(\sigma)$ for any $\varphi\in\Phi$

holds.

Indeed, let's we assume that $\cal T_\Sigma$ is a topology on $\Sigma$ for which the above statement holds and thus let be $\psi$ a function from a space $\Lambda$ to $\Sigma$. So, we know that $\varphi\circ\psi$ is continuous at $\lambda\in\Lambda$ if and only if for any net $(\lambda_j)_{j\in J}$ in $\Lambda$ based on any directed set $(J,\preceq_J)$ which converges to $\lambda$ the net $\big((\varphi\circ\psi)(\lambda_j)\big)_{j\in J}$ converges to $(\varphi\circ\psi)(\lambda)$ but if this happens then by hypothesis $\big(\psi(\lambda_j)\big)_{j\in J}$ converges to $\psi(\lambda)$ which means that $\psi$ is continuous at $\lambda$ so that $\psi$ is continuous if and only if and only if $\varphi\circ\psi$ is continuous for any $\varphi\in\Phi$ but the initial topology $\cal T_\frak F$ corresponding to any collection of functions $\frak F$ defined in a set $X$ is just the unique topology on $X$ such that a function $g$ form a space $Y$ to $X$ is continuous if and only if $f\circ g$ is continuous for each $f\in\frak F$ so that $\cal T_\Sigma$ is just equal to $\cal T_\Phi$.

Now let be $\cal T_\varphi$ the topology of the codomain $\Lambda_\varphi$ of any $\varphi\in\Phi$ so that let's we prove that $\cal T_\Phi$ is the unique topology on $\Sigma$ for which the statement

> A filter $\cal F$ in $\Sigma$ coverges to any $\sigma$ if and only if the filter $\cal F_\varphi$ generated by $\varphi$ converges to $\varphi(\sigma)$ for any $\varphi\in\Phi$.

holds.

Indeed, clearly if $\cal F$ converges to $\sigma$ then $\cal F_\varphi$ convereges to $\varphi(\sigma)$ by continuity of $\varphi$ with respect $\cal T_\Phi$; conversely, if $\cal F_\varphi$ converges to $\varphi(\sigma)$ then it contains the neighborhood system $\cal U\big(\varphi(\sigma)\big)$ of $\varphi(\sigma)$ in $\Lambda_\varphi$ and so if the collection
$$
\varphi(\mathcal F):=\big\{\varphi[F]:F\in\cal F\big\}
$$
is a base for $\cal F_\varphi$ then for any $U_\varphi\in\cal U\big(\varphi(\sigma)\big)$ there exists $F(U_\varphi)\in\cal F$ such that
$$
F(U_\varphi)\subseteq\varphi^{-1}[U_\varphi]
$$
but by definition of initial topology we know that for any $U\in\cal U(\sigma)$ there exists $(\varphi_i,U_{\varphi_i})_{i\in n}\in\prod_{i\in n}\Phi\times\prod_{i\in n}\cal U\big(\varphi_i(\sigma)\big)$ such that
$$
\sigma\in\bigcap_{i\in n}\varphi^{-1}_i[U_{\varphi_i}]\subseteq U
$$
so that by the inclusion
$$
\bigcap_{i\in n}F(U_{\varphi_i})\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in n}\varphi^{-1}_i[U_{\varphi_i}]
$$
we conclude that (remember that a filter is closed for finite intersection and for superset) $U$ lies in $\cal F$ and so finally $\cal F$ converges to $\sigma$.

Now let's we assume that $\cal T_\Sigma$ is a topology on $\Sigma$ for which the second statement holds and thus let be $\psi$ a function from a space $\Lambda$ to $\Sigma$. So, we know that $\varphi\circ\psi$ is continuous at $\lambda\in\Lambda$ if and only if for any filter $\cal F$ in $\Lambda$ converging to any $\lambda$ the filter $\cal F_{\varphi\circ\psi}$ generated by $\varphi\circ\psi$ converges to $(\varphi\circ\psi)(\lambda)$ but if this happens then by hypothesis $\cal F_{\varphi\circ\psi}$ converges to $\psi(\lambda)$ which means that $\psi$ is continuous at $\lambda$ so that $\psi$ is continuous if and only if and only if $\varphi\circ\psi$ is continuous for any $\varphi\in\Phi$ and so by the same arguments we applied for nets now we again conclude that $\cal T_\Sigma$ is just equal to $\cal T_\Phi$.